# Amazon ELB and use of address / server names across multiple servers

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, postgresql, amazon-elb

I am setting up Nginx servers behind the ELB. I set up so that api.app.com points to an ELB.
I wonder which addresses I should use for remote connections, Nginx settings etc..

1) For example, in Nginx:

Should I  do

```
 server {
          listen 80;
#What is the right line here:
#              server_name <WWW.NAME.COM> OR <ec2-.....compute-1.amazonaws.com> OR <MLB-....amazonaws.com>?;
         passenger_enabled on;
         .....
 }
```

2) I connect servers behind ELB to remote Postgres database. In Postgres settings should I open the ELB address (MLB-...amazonws.com) or to individual EC2 IPs?

Answer (score 2):

The `server_name` should be set to your web site's hostname, that people will actually type in.